# Active Directory: Check password from another domain but use user object from origin domain

Tags: windows, unix, ldap

The setup I have is a department AD domain A which has UNIX attributes added for our Solaris (LDAP), Linux(sssd) & Windows systems which works for our users for many years.

Problem our users have 2 passwords one for our department and one for the University.

Domain A - Unix Schema attributes for our users

Domain B - All users NO Unix attributes

Now I want to use the Corporate AD for the password ONLY so we have one password the same password

So:

- User logs into Domain A from any client
- 'AD server on Domain A' checks Password on Donain B
- Properties of user object in Domain A to be used (UID, Groups, Drive location,  etc)

Again, I want to use all user Properties in domain A, but check password in donain B.

My understanding of Trusts relationships is that the above isn't possible? Since you are given back the user properties of domain B.

Thanks
Andrew

Comment: Which OS is this for?

Comment: Domain A (our department) is on Windows Server, but accessesed from Windows clients, Linux (sssd) clients and Solaris (ldap) clients.
Doman B (Company domain) is another Windows Server